# A flagrant bit of anarchy yearning for direction

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I report more sentences surrounding the one in the title, which is a monologue from the movie Black River:

"A community is a funny little animal: 8903 bits of self-interests heading up to something greater... or less! *A flagrant bit of anarchy yearning for direction*, desperate for a guiding hand. And from whom? A part of that small self-interest? Oh, I think not! The world will be just when it's ruled by a philosopher king"

I'm not a native speaker and am having hard times understanding what the sentence in the title should mean, especially the "flagrant bit" (bit is used before too and I'm not fully sure what it means in this context).

Comment: A "bit" is a small piece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have looked up **flagrant** in a dictionary and found that it means blatant or overt. Likewise **anarchy**: unruliness or disorder; and **yearning for**: craving, or thirsting for. The word **direction** is being used here to mean guidance. And in fact the words 'yearning for direction' mean the same as the next words: 'desperate for a guiding hand.'

So we've got:

A community is...a blatant small piece (thanks to Hot Licks) of unruliness craving guidance, craving guidance.